# How to automatically test my webpack-bundled web against FUOC?

Tags: css, node.js, testing, web, webpack

I've built a React + Redux web which gets bundled with webpack. Due to a bundling error my web started to show [FUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) behaviour (some components didn't inject their CSS to the server response, so there was a 'flash' of unstyled parts of the application before the final CSS was loaded). Other errors included FUOC for 3rd party components (which required manual work to do).

I have automated test for the server and different parts of my web. But how do I automatically test for FOUC (with my node.js toolchain)? I tought about selenium and phantomjs, but this seems like an overkill, and I still don't know how I could detect it.

Comment: What was the error? Tried to solve?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran no error, I'm just not sure about a reasonable approach. In addition I would prefer an "easy" and "lightweight" solution without running a whole (headless) browser, but simple JS-based tests instead.

Comment: Share your webpack config

Comment: Is [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) an option? Don't have to do much except configure it, they do the heavy lifting for ya

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran there's nothing special about my webpack config (it's auto-generated due to few output webs, though). What I want to do is to test the final web, which should preferably be webpack-agnostic.

Comment: @DanM. as far as I understand they just execute your unit tests on different platforms - and the unit tests themselves are what I what to achieve ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prevent FOUC by ensuring elements with FOUC are only visible when their CSS is fully loaded. To make it simple, I apply it to the entire body. For example:

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Then, later in the CCS file or loaded with some component ...

```
body {
    opacity:1;
}
```

This effectively hides the elements during render time while they're still being drawn. Working backward from this, you can create a unit test to run prior to the loading of the CSS for your element/component to test for visibility or other CSS properties that should be loaded before the element becomes visible.  The trick would be to ensure these tests are run at the appropriate time at each stage of the element's render.

```
// Test for FOUC load component then verify for no visiblity ...    
expect($('#testElement').is(':visible')).toBe(false)

/** 
 * load component/elemnt css here then ... 
 */

// then test for visibility or other css properties ...
expect($('#testElement').is(':visible')).toBe(true)
```